# C++ Exporting png resource to file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, resources

Visual Studio 2015, console application. Trying to work with resources. I added some png images to resources. If I export image from IDE it's ok. Now I try to do the same via c++; Here the code

```
HRSRC myResource = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(SEND_MSG_PNG), L"PNG");
if (myResource == NULL)
{
    fatal("Could not locate dialog box.");
    return;
}
DWORD myResourceSize = SizeofResource(NULL, myResource);
log("Resource size %d", myResourceSize);
HGLOBAL myResourceData = LoadResource(NULL, myResource);
if (myResourceData == NULL)
{
    fatal("Could not load dialog box.");
    return;
}
void* lpResLock = LockResource(myResourceData);
if (lpResLock == NULL)
{
    fatal("Could not lock dialog box.");
    return;
}
FILE *fh;
fopen_s(&fh, "d:/test2.png", "w+");
fwrite(lpResLock, myResourceSize, 1, fh);
fclose(fh);
```

And here the problem begin. If I export this file via IDE it's 852 bytes. Lets call it test.png And test2.png is 1041 bytes. I opened both files in HEX editor. First 5 bytes are same 89 50 4E 47 0D. The problem is that all viewers says test2.png is corrupted while test.png is ok. [test.png data](http://pastebin.com/0ex3NwcT) [test2.png](http://pastebin.com/1XzZUi0q) How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mode `"wb+"` in fopen_s instead, to avoid any text data conversions (like line endings patching, etc). Added `b` means "binary".